# Why am I getting "The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
 private void GetTABLE()
 {
    conn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("`GetAllTablesProduct`", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    ListView1.DataSource = dt;
    ListView1.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
}
```

And this is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetAllTablesProduct]    
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Product    
    ORDER BY ID DESC     
END
```

Comment: Well when are you calling the `GetTABLE` method?

Comment: I dont Understand Can Yoy Explain Little Bit

Comment: I can't really explain it any simpler. Somewhere in your code you will be calling this method...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using script manager in your page and written server side code in aspx page like **<%=servercode%>** or **<%response.write(content)%>**.

Please remove this type of code if you find that.